# How to fetch the second line data from text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file-handling

How to fetch the second line data from text file in Python.

I have a text file and in file there are some data in line by line_

```
Dog
Cat
Cow
```

How to fetch the second line which is “Cat” and store in a variable in python

```
var =    # “Cat”
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place the text file in the same directory with your Python code, which could be the following:

```
with open("animals.txt", "r") as f:
    animals = [line.strip() for line in f]

second_line = animals[1]
```

Now, the variable "second_line" contains the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a file, then read line by line while counting the line number as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_path = "data/animals.txt"
    var = None
    with open(input_path, "r") as fin:
        n_lines = 0
        for line in fin:
            n_lines += 1
            if 2 == n_lines:
                var = line.strip()
                break
    print(var)
```

Result:

```
Cat
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is big, you may avoid reading all file and use readline to read one line twice:

```
with open ('file.txt') as file:
    line = file.readline()
    line = file.readline()

print(line)
```

...or check 'seek' method to start reading at specific character index.